# AWS Cognito - ResourceNotFoundException and GroupExistsException in test cases

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-js-v3

I'm writing test cases that repeatedly call `CreateGroup`, `UpdateGroup` and `DeleteGroup` for AWS Cognito and validate if these changes were successful by reading the respective group via `GetGroup` via the AWS SDK for JS v3.

However, I noticed a strange behavior that a call to `DeleteGroup` yield an `ResourceNotFoundException` but a subsequent call to `CreateGroup` yields an `GroupExistsException` for the same group name.

It seems like the AWS Cognito API is eventually consistent, but I could't find any information online.

UPDATE:
I created a test repository to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/zirkelc/aws-cognito-groups
The `UserPoolId` and `region` must be changed to your own resources. Then this example can be started with `npx ts-node index` and prints the following outputs:

````
$ npx ts-node index

create group

get group

delete group

create group
GroupExistsException A group with the name already exists.

get group
ResourceNotFoundException Group not found.

delete group
ResourceNotFoundException Group not found.

create group
GroupExistsException A group with the name already exists.

get group
ResourceNotFoundException Group not found.

delete group
ResourceNotFoundException Group not found.
...
```
````

Comment: Can you please share how you're doing these calls?

Comment: I added a test repo to my question. I'm using the `@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider` to create/get/delete the groups.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I arrived here trying to address the same problem.  The way the Cognito API is implemented suggests it's using DynamoDB internally, which *could* be using eventually consistent writes/reads.  Just a hunch, but I'm going down the same path you are

Comment: That could well be the reason. I opened an issue on the AWS SDK repo and they are investigating it: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3825